# Feed Tableau data using getData() into D3 chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js, tableau-api

Does anyone have any suggestions for formatting and feeding underlying data using Tableau's [getData()](http://onlinehelp.tableau.com/v10.0/api/js_api/en-us/JavaScriptAPI/js_api_samples_get_data.html) function into this [D3 Doughnut Chart](http://jsfiddle.net/Qh9X5/1196/)?  I understand I need to create an array for the underlying data but am unsure how to do so.  The underlying data is in this JSON format:

```
[[
    {
        "value":"Thais Sissman",
        "formattedValue":"Thais Sissman"
    },
    {
        "value":"-0.6860335195530726",
        "formattedValue":"-68.6%"
    },
    {
        "value":"-3.3156",
        "formattedValue":"($3)"
    },
    {
        "value":"793",
        "formattedValue":"793"
    },
    {
        "value":"4.833000000000001",
        "formattedValue":"$5"
    }
],
[
    {
        "value":"Lela Donovan",
        "formattedValue":"Lela Donovan"
    },
    {
        "value":"0.0875",
        "formattedValue":"8.8%"
    },
    {
        "value":"0.4641",
        "formattedValue":"$0"
    },
    {    
        "value":"792",
        "formattedValue":"792"
    },
    {
        "value":"5.304",
        "formattedValue":"$5"
    }
]]
```

Here is my JavaScript code:

```
$(document).ready(function initViz() {
var containerDiv = document.getElementById("vizContainer"),
    url = "https://SERVER-NAME/t/gfm/views/Superstore/Customers?:embed=y&:showShareOptions=true&:display_count=no&:showVizHome=no",
    options = {
        hideTabs: true,
        hideToolbar: true,
        onFirstInteractive: function () {
        document.getElementById('getData').disabled = false; // Enable our button
                   }
                };
            viz = new tableau.Viz(containerDiv, url, options);
        });

//when viz is loaded (onFirstInteractive), request data
function getSummaryData() {
    options = {
        maxRows: 0, // Max rows to return. Use 0 to return all rows
        ignoreAliases: false,
        ignoreSelection: true,
        includeAllColumns: false
};

sheet = viz.getWorkbook().getActiveSheet();

//if active tab is a worksheet, get data from that sheet
if (sheet.getSheetType() === 'worksheet') {
    sheet.getSummaryDataAsync(options).then(function (t) {
        buildMenu(t);
});

//if active sheet is a dashboard get data from a specified sheet
}   else {
    worksheetArray = viz.getWorkbook().getActiveSheet().getWorksheets();
    for (var i = 0; i < worksheetArray.length; i++) {
        worksheet = worksheetArray[i];
        sheetName = worksheet.getName();
        if (sheetName == 'CustomerRank') {
            worksheetArray[i].getSummaryDataAsync(options).then(function (t) {
            var data = t.getData();  
            var columns = t.getColumns();
            table = t; 
            var tgt = document.getElementById("dataTarget");
            tgt.innerHTML = "<h4>Underlying Data:</h4><p>" + JSON.stringify(table.getData()) + "</p>";
            buildVisual(t);
            });
        }
    }
    }
} 

function buildVisual(table) {

//the data returned from the tableau API
var columns = table.getColumns();
var data = table.getData();

//convert to field:values convention
function reduceToObjects(cols,data) {
    var fieldNameMap = $.map(cols, function(col) { return col.getFieldName(); });
    var dataToReturn = $.map(data, function(d) {
        return d.reduce(function(memo, value, idx) {
           memo[fieldNameMap[idx]] = value.value; return memo;
        }, {});
    });

    return dataToReturn;
}

var niceData = reduceToObjects(columns, data);

var svg = d3.select('body')
  .append('svg')
  .attr('width', 400)
  .attr('height', 200)
  .attr('id', 'chart');

// add an SVG group element for each user
var series = svg.selectAll('g.series')
  .data(d3.keys(dataTarget))
  .enter()
  .append('g')
  .attr('class', 'series');

var width = 300,
    height = 300,
    radius = Math.min(width, height) / 2;

var color = d3.scale.category20();

var pie = d3.layout.pie()
    .sort(null);

var piedata = pie(niceData.data);

var arc = d3.svg.arc()
    .innerRadius(radius - 100)
    .outerRadius(radius - 50);

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")");

var path = svg.selectAll("path")
    .data(piedata)
    .enter().append("path")
    .attr("fill", function(d, i) { return color(i); })
    .attr("d", arc);

svg.selectAll("text").data(piedata)
    .enter()
    .append("text")
    .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
    .attr("x", function(d) {
        var a = d.startAngle + (d.endAngle - d.startAngle)/2 - Math.PI/2;
        d.cx = Math.cos(a) * (radius - 75);
        return d.x = Math.cos(a) * (radius - 20);
    })
    .attr("y", function(d) {
        var a = d.startAngle + (d.endAngle - d.startAngle)/2 - Math.PI/2;
        d.cy = Math.sin(a) * (radius - 75);
        return d.y = Math.sin(a) * (radius - 20);
    })
    .text(function(d) { return d.value; })
    .each(function(d) {
        var bbox = this.getBBox();
        d.sx = d.x - bbox.width/2 - 2;
        d.ox = d.x + bbox.width/2 + 2;
        d.sy = d.oy = d.y + 5;
    });

svg.append("defs").append("marker")
    .attr("id", "circ")
    .attr("markerWidth", 6)
    .attr("markerHeight", 6)
    .attr("refX", 3)
    .attr("refY", 3)
    .append("circle")
    .attr("cx", 3)
    .attr("cy", 3)
    .attr("r", 3);

svg.selectAll("path.pointer").data(piedata).enter()
    .append("path")
    .attr("class", "pointer")
    .style("fill", "none")
    .style("stroke", "black")
    .attr("marker-end", "url(#circ)")
    .attr("d", function(d) {
        if(d.cx > d.ox) {
            return "M" + d.sx + "," + d.sy + "L" + d.ox + "," + d.oy + " " + d.cx + "," + d.cy;
        } else {
            return "M" + d.ox + "," + d.oy + "L" + d.sx + "," + d.sy + " " + d.cx + "," + d.cy;
        }
    });
}
```